# Help building a Thief

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

Can someone explain how many Feats and Powers I should pick? I'm making a Rogue (Thief) from "Heroes of the Fallen Lands".

In page 41 under skills, powers, and feats to refer my  specific class entry.
Then under Class Features and Powers "Note which class features and power you gain at 1st level, as specified on the Thief Heroic Tier table".

There it says "Level = 1 Feats known = 1".

But it's also says "For your two tricks at 1st level" and Under Feats "Choose one feat at 1st level."

So what and how many powers (at-will, encounter, and daily) do I choose? Please help!

Comment: Liran as you seem to be new to the game, I highly suggest getting access to the Character Builder, it's a software which helps you build characters breaking everything down in little choices and giving you at the end a complete character sheet. See if you have a friend with a subscription to DnD Insider, if he lets you use his character builder you will be finished in no time, and don't worry building the first character is always the hardest.

Answer (score 2):

A level 1 Thief should have the following:

- 1 feat (unless you pick human for your race, in which case you get 2)
- 2 tricks (choose from the ones listed on pages 176 through 179)
- the Backstab utility encounter power

Essentials classes (classes from any book with a name like "Heroes of X") usually don't pick at-will, encounter, and daily powers the way pre-Essentials classes do. Thieves don't ever get daily powers, and they pick encounter powers less often than other classes do.

Page 174 of "Heroes of the Fallen Lands" lists all the things a Thief gets other than feats. Feats are actually pretty simple: you get a feat at every level that ends in 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, or 0, no matter *what* class you are; humans get an extra feat at 1st level.

Comment: How about Ranger And Hunter.
and how i know what i sould have in eche classes?

Comment: @Liran: There should be a table called "Heroic Hunter" a couple pages into the section of the book about Hunters; that will have everything you need to know about Hunters except feats, and feats are the same for everyone.

Comment: @Liran: For Essentials characters you get whatever the class' table says you get plus a feat.

Comment: In case you think not e-classes getting less powers/choices is bad, they are built this way because their class features are usually incredibly powerful when compared to non-essentials classes. I would highly recommend going with an e-class if its your first time.